# wkhtmltopdf wait for condition before printing

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

We are using wkhtmltopdf to convert dynamic html pages to pdf.
We need to wait until all the ajax requests are finished.

Is there a possibility to delay the printing by a condition?

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't an option for this because it breaks down when you think about it too much. Imagine a page that continuously polls an AJAX endpoint every N seconds, something that is actually very common. Your scenario might not have this but wkhtmltopdf doesn't know that and there's no real way to flag that you have a fixed load path.

Comment: I don't want wkhtmltopdf to wait my ajax requests, I would need an option to add my wait condition, maybe a script which can tell wkhtmltopdf when to print.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `--window-status` option, see this [post on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wkhtmltopdf-general/vWDe5hUAyJ8/2XbXM2g1ZtYJ).

Answer (score 10):

If you can change the javascript code of the webpage then add this line of code to your javascript when you are certain everything is done loading:

```
if (your_condition_is_met_here){
    window.status = 'ready_to_print';
}
```

Then pass a flag --window-status ready_to_print to wkhtmltopdf.  For example:

```
wkhtmltopdf --window-status ready_to_print map.html map.pdf
```

See: [wkhtmltopdf javascript delay for output of google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578457/wkhtmltopdf-javascript-delay-for-output-of-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the --javascript-delay option.

Comment: I want to be sure that every request is finished and I don't want to delay more then needed. So --jvascript-delay is not good.