# plotly js: how to run my javascript ONLY after plot image is loaded

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf, plotly

When using a plotly graph of any sort with the Javascript API (plotly.js, not plotly-nodejs), how can I run some javascript ONLY after the graph has loaded? I'm looking for the mechanism in the plotly javascript API that, for example, does the same thing that 'addListenerOnce', in conjunction with 'tilesloaded' or 'ready', do when using the Google Maps API.

For example, let's say I want to simply display an alert immediately after rendering the example shown at https://plot.ly/~PlotBot/685, for which the html and js code can be seen at https://plot.ly/~PlotBot/685.js.

There are many reasons to do this, but the one I am faced with now is using wkhtml2pdf, which must wait for the page to be rendered before displaying (see [wkhtmltopdf javascript delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578457/wkhtmltopdf-javascript-delay/32280611#32280611)) (Yes, I know I can use --javascript-delay with wkhtml2pdf, but hardcoding a fixed amount of time and hoping that your program waited long enough for its next steps to succeed is not the solution I'm looking for-- and besides, that approach is specific to wkhtml2pdf and does not answer the general question).

Prefer a browser-independent solution but at the least, need one that works on Chrome

Comment: [How to detect when an image is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)

Comment: it's not clear to me how this would work in the context of a plotly chart. can you provide any code snippet showing how this would work for the example in the question?

Comment: Plotly.plot will also return a promise, so you can run `Plotly.plot('chartDiv', data, layout).then(function(chartDiv){
        // do stuff 
    });`

Comment: thanks, tried that too, were you able to get that to work at the right time? when did that with an alert statement in the promise function, it fired before the chart was rendered.

Comment: I see you've made a github issue. Could you post an example to the issue and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the promise, as mentioned in the comments above, is the correct solution.  However, the promise fires before the first animation frame is done rendering.  As a workaround, you can subscribe to the promise and then wait for the animation frame to finish, using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

*EDIT:* A single animation frame was sufficient for Firefox, but not Chrome.  So I'm editing to use a pair of animation frames, which appears to fix the issue in Chrome, and should continue to work in Firefox.  This of course is just a workaround for an issue in Plotly, as the promise should not resolve until the plot has actually rendered.

Here's an example:

```js
var trace1 = {
  z: [[8.83, 8.89, 8.81, 8.87, 8.9, 8.87], [8.89, 8.94, 8.85, 8.94, 8.96, 8.92], [8.84, 8.9, 8.82, 8.92, 8.93, 8.91], [8.79, 8.85, 8.79, 8.9, 8.94, 8.92], [8.79, 8.88, 8.81, 8.9, 8.95, 8.92], [8.8, 8.82, 8.78, 8.91, 8.94, 8.92], [8.75, 8.78, 8.77, 8.91, 8.95, 8.92], [8.8, 8.8, 8.77, 8.91, 8.95, 8.94], [8.74, 8.81, 8.76, 8.93, 8.98, 8.99], [8.89, 8.99, 8.92, 9.1, 9.13, 9.11], [8.97, 8.97, 8.91, 9.09, 9.11, 9.11], [9.04, 9.08, 9.05, 9.25, 9.28, 9.27], [9, 9.01, 9, 9.2, 9.23, 9.2], [8.99, 8.99, 8.98, 9.18, 9.2, 9.19], [8.93, 8.97, 8.97, 9.18, 9.2, 9.18]], 
  colorbar: {
    xpad: 0, 
    ypad: 0
  }, 
  showscale: false, 
  type: "surface", 
  uid: "3f95e8", 
  zmax: 9.28, 
  zmin: 8.74
};
var trace2 = {
  z: [[9.83, 9.89, 9.81, 9.87, 9.9, 9.87], [9.89, 9.94, 9.85, 9.94, 9.96, 9.92], [9.84, 9.9, 9.82, 9.92, 9.93, 9.91], [9.79, 9.85, 9.79, 9.9, 9.94, 9.92], [9.79, 9.88, 9.81, 9.9, 9.95, 9.92], [9.8, 9.82, 9.78, 9.91, 9.94, 9.92], [9.75, 9.78, 9.77, 9.91, 9.95, 9.92], [9.8, 9.8, 9.77, 9.91, 9.95, 9.94], [9.74, 9.81, 9.76, 9.93, 9.98, 9.99], [9.89, 9.99, 9.92, 10.1, 10.13, 10.11], [9.97, 9.97, 9.91, 10.09, 10.11, 10.11], [10.04, 10.08, 10.05, 10.25, 10.28, 10.27], [10, 10.01, 10, 10.2, 10.23, 10.2], [9.99, 9.99, 9.98, 10.18, 10.2, 10.19], [9.93, 9.97, 9.97, 10.18, 10.2, 10.18]], 
  opacity: 0.9, 
  showscale: false, 
  type: "surface", 
  uid: "443a24", 
  zmax: 10.28, 
  zmin: 9.74
};
var trace3 = {
  z: [[7.83, 7.89, 7.81, 7.87, 7.9, 7.87], [7.89, 7.94, 7.85, 7.94, 7.96, 7.92], [7.84, 7.9, 7.82, 7.92, 7.93, 7.91], [7.79, 7.85, 7.79, 7.9, 7.94, 7.92], [7.79, 7.88, 7.81, 7.9, 7.95, 7.92], [7.8, 7.82, 7.78, 7.91, 7.94, 7.92], [7.75, 7.78, 7.77, 7.91, 7.95, 7.92], [7.8, 7.8, 7.77, 7.91, 7.95, 7.94], [7.74, 7.81, 7.76, 7.93, 7.98, 7.99], [7.89, 7.99, 7.92, 8.1, 8.13, 8.11], [7.97, 7.97, 7.91, 8.09, 8.11, 8.11], [8.04, 8.08, 8.05, 8.25, 8.28, 8.27], [8, 8.01, 8, 8.2, 8.23, 8.2], [7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 8.18, 8.2, 8.19], [7.93, 7.97, 7.97, 8.18, 8.2, 8.18]], 
  opacity: 0.9, 
  showscale: false, 
  type: "surface", 
  uid: "47cf99", 
  zmax: 8.28, 
  zmin: 7.74
};
var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];
var layout = {
  autosize: false, 
  height: 200, 
  margin: {
    r: 0, 
    t: 0, 
    autoexpand: false, 
    b: 0, 
    l: 0
  }, 
  scene: {
    aspectmode: "manual", 
    aspectratio: {
      x: 1, 
      y: 1, 
      z: 1
    }, 
    camera: {
      center: {
        x: 0, 
        y: 0, 
        z: 0
      }, 
      eye: {
        x: 1.59999582495, 
        y: 1.57131061558, 
        z: 0.970117065684
      }, 
      up: {
        x: 0, 
        y: 0, 
        z: 1
      }
    }
  }, 
  width: 650
};
Plotly.plot('plotly-div', data, layout).then(function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      window.alert('Your plot is done.');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="plotly-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does fire later than the promise, but unfortunately it still executes before the image is visible, at least when I try it on Chrome

Comment: Odd, I thought I had tested on Chrome, but I posted from Firefox and after your comment I saw my post did not work in Chrome.  I've added a second animation frame delay, which should work in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

on this page: https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/
under

> Start plotting!

You are asked to create a `div` with an `id`.

By adding `onload` as a `attribute` (or in javascript)

You get this: `<div id="tester" onload="myFunction()" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>`

"myFunction" can contain the code you want execute after loading the image.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to do this with plotly.js, not plotly-nodejs. The plot() function there does not seem to have this callback option

Comment: @mwag my bad, can you pass an ID, that way you can check `onload` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp for image right?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. if there is, I'd be interested to learn

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was, I don't know of any way to do that that works. I tried that and it doesn't work. For example, if you change your code to say "alert('hi')" instead of "myFunction()" then, at least on Chrome, it doesn't ever fire

Comment: @mwag what about `if (document.getElementById("id form chart") ) { //code goes here}` ?